# Web API Controller not found on PUT

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, put

I am having trouble finding the put action of a web api 2 controller.  I'm
using MVC5.  The GET action in the controller is found and is working well when called.  I have tried several different ways of hitting this, but to no avail.  I would appreciate any hints.

The jquery call:

```
 var data = {
        id: 1,
        text: 'test'
    };

var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    url: serviceRoot  + "Approval/" +  id,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: jsondata,
    success: function (results) {
        alert('Content saved.');
    }
})
```

The request object used in the controller:

```
public class ContentRequest
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

Route from startup:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace SeacretGarden.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ApprovalController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, ContentRequest content)
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
   The resolution to my problem was to add the following to my web.config file:
 ( I am using MVC5 with Web API controllers )

```
<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
           path="*."
           verb="*"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    </handlers>
```

Comment: Have you seen this information: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications -- it is a common problem.

Comment: Reviewing now.  There are some web.config settings I think I overlooked.

Comment: The main reason this config issue is so common is because there are out-of-the-box scenarios where the configs already exhibit the 'problem' -- ostensibly this is an issue of trying to keep a vanilla configuration as secure as possible (i.e. securing things more prone to abuse such as PUT or PATCH http verbs, unless explicitly enabled).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. David, the article gave me some ideas on the web.config file additions I needed to make.  They are part of my edited question.  Thanks again.

Comment: So it appears the primary issue was having WebDAV, and not having the ExtensionlessUrlHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to my problem was to add the following to my web.config file: ( I am using MVC5 with Web API controllers ):

```
<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
           path="*."
           verb="*"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    </handlers>
```